# Making storage plugin on Apache Drill to HDFS

Tags: apache, hadoop, hdfs, apache-drill, hadoop-plugins

I'm trying to make storage plugin for Hadoop (hdfs) and Apache Drill. 
Actually I'm confused and I don't know what to set as port for hdfs:// connection, and what to set for location.
This is my plugin:

```
 {
 "type": "file",
 "enabled": true,
 "connection": "hdfs://localhost:54310",
 "workspaces": {
 "root": {
  "location": "/",
  "writable": false,
  "defaultInputFormat": null
},
"tmp": {
  "location": "/tmp",
  "writable": true,
  "defaultInputFormat": null
}
 },
"formats": {
  "psv": {
  "type": "text",
  "extensions": [
    "tbl"
  ],
  "delimiter": "|"
},
"csv": {
  "type": "text",
  "extensions": [
    "csv"
  ],
  "delimiter": ","
},
"tsv": {
  "type": "text",
  "extensions": [
    "tsv"
  ],
  "delimiter": "\t"
},
"parquet": {
  "type": "parquet"
},
"json": {
  "type": "json"
},
"avro": {
  "type": "avro"
   }
 }
}
```

So, is ti correct to set *localhost:54310* because I got that with command:

```
 hdfs -getconf -nnRpcAddresses
```

or it is :8020 ?

Second question, what do I need to set for  location? My hadoop folder is in:

```
/usr/local/hadoop
```

, and there you can find /etc /bin /lib /log  ... So, do I need to set location on my datanode, or?

Third question. When I'm connecting to Drill, I'm going through **sqlline** and than connecting on my zookeeper like:

```
  !connect jdbc:drill:zk=localhost:2181
```

My question here is, after I make storage plugin and when I connect to Drill with zk, can I query hdfs file?

I'm very sorry if this is a noob question but I haven't find anything useful on internet or at least it haven't helped me. 
If you are able to explain me some stuff, I'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Drill [docs](https://drill.apache.org/docs/file-system-storage-plugin/),

```
  {
    "type" : "file",
    "enabled" : true,
    "connection" : "hdfs://10.10.30.156:8020/",
    "workspaces" : {
      "root" : {
        "location" : "/user/root/drill",
        "writable" : true,
        "defaultInputFormat" : null
      }
    },
    "formats" : {
      "json" : {
        "type" : "json"
      }
    }
  }
```

**In `"connection"`**,

put namenode server address.

If you are not sure about this address.
*Check `fs.default.name` or `fs.defaultFS` properties in `core-site.xml`.*

**Coming to `"workspaces"`**,

you can save workspaces in this. In the above example, there is a `workspace` with name `root` and location `/user/root/drill`.
**This is your HDFS location.**

If you have files under `/user/root/drill` hdfs directory, you can query them using this workspace name.

Example: `abc` is under this directory.

```
 select * from dfs.root.`abc.csv`
```

---

After successfully creating the plugin, you can start drill and start querying .

You can query any directory irrespective to workspaces.

Say you want to query `employee.json` in `/tmp/data` hdfs directory.

Query is :

```
select * from dfs.`/tmp/data/employee.json`
```

Comment: Hmm, in meanwhile I made hadoop multi node cluster. But, I still can't query hdfs folder. I checked out my *core-site.xml*  and in connection stands: `hdfs://hadoop-master:9000` . I went in apache drill *dfs* plugin and in *connection* i wrote exactly the same line. Also I made folder in hdfs and named him **parquet**. When I'm trying to query from drill, this is my query:  `SELECT * FROM dfs.'/parquet/file.parquet';` and I'm getting this error: 
*Query failed: PARSE ERROR: From line 1, column 21 to line 1, column 23: Table 'dfs./file.parquet' not found
[wq9u34jnj1223 on hadoop-master:31010]

Comment: @Superbrain_bug check last line of my answer. Its ` symbol not single quote (') Now try: ```SELECT * FROM dfs.`/parquet/file.parquet`;```

Comment: Yeah yeah, I have been using him, I miss typed, I'm sry
Also, when I'm trying to use `SHOW FILES` with hdfs:// configuration, I got an error like this : **Query failed: System Error: Failure handling SQL.**
But, I can switch schemas..

Comment: @Superbrain_bug I am assuming your plugin name is **dfs** and it added successfully. you are trying - `use dfs;` and then `show files;` Right?

Comment: I actually did it. The problem obviously was in Apache Drill version. I used 0.8. and after I upgraded to 1.8. it started working. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @Superbrain_bug I was about to ask for the drill version..:D

Comment: Yeah yeah I solved it. The sentence where you said to check for URL and port of hadoop - *core-site.xml*, also helped me a lot. Ty man! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem, Drill cannot read dfs server. Finally, the problem is cause by namenode port.
The default address of namenode web UI is http://localhost:50070/.

The default address of namenode server is hdfs://localhost:8020/.