# How to access HDFS from Drill in embedded mode?

Tags: hdfs, apache-drill

Trying to run apache drill on a [single node](https://drill.apache.org/docs/embedded-mode-prerequisites/), following an [article](https://acadgild.com/blog/querying-hdfs-using-apache-drill) for accessing HDFS from embedded drill, but am getting errors

```sh
➜  Apps /home/hph_etl/Apps/apache-drill-1.16.0/bin/sqlline -u "jdbc:drill:zk=local;schema=dfs"

...

apache drill (dfs)> select * from dfs.`tmp/`;
Error: RESOURCE ERROR: Failed to load schema for "dfs"!

java.net.ConnectException: Call From HW04.ucera.local/172.18.4.49 to localhost:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused


[Error Id: 2fd541ee-2290-4cf8-979b-aca3c77859e2 ] (state=,code=0)
apache drill (dfs)> !q
Closing: org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillConnectionImpl
```

where the dfs storage plugin file looks like...

```sh
{
  "type": "file",
  "connection": "hdfs://localhost:8020/",
  "config": null,
  "workspaces": {
    "tmp": {
      "location": "/tmp",
      "writable": true,
      "defaultInputFormat": null,
      "allowAccessOutsideWorkspace": false
    },
    "root": {
      "location": "/",
      "writable": false,
      "defaultInputFormat": null,
      "allowAccessOutsideWorkspace": false
    }
  },
  "formats": {
    "psv": {
      "type": "text",
      "extensions": [
        "tbl"
   ....
}
```

(note that I don't really know how to determine what port the hdfs connection is supposed to be) and the error message's link (http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused) goes nowhere.
Attempting an alternate solution from another SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33442630/8236733) throws errors:

```sh
➜  Apps /home/hph_etl/Apps/apache-drill-1.16.0/bin/sqlline -u "jdbc:drill:drillbit=localhost:31010;schema=dfs"
Error: Failure in connecting to Drill: org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.RpcException: CONNECTION : io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:31010 (state=,code=0)
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Failure in connecting to Drill: org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.RpcException: CONNECTION : io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:31010
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillConnectionImpl.<init>(DrillConnectionImpl.java:178)
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillJdbc41Factory.newDrillConnection(DrillJdbc41Factory.java:67)
```

Not sure what to check at this point; Any debugging suggestions or fixes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, what worked was **setting the connection hdfs IP to be the IP of the hadoop cluster's namenode** (from another SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39248682) on connecting to HDFS in general), so the drill dfs storage plugin config looks like:

```
{
  "type": "file",
  "connection": "hdfs://localhost:8020/",
  "config": null,
  "workspaces": {
    "tmp": {
      "location": "/tmp",
      "writable": true,
      "defaultInputFormat": null,
      "allowAccessOutsideWorkspace": false
    },
   ....
}
```

and we can do

```sh
➜  bin /home/hph_etl/Apps/apache-drill-1.16.0/bin/sqlline -u "jdbc:drill:zk=local;schema=dfs"
Apache Drill 1.16.0
"Got Drill?"
apache drill (dfs)> select * from dfs.`tmp/`;
Error: PERMISSION ERROR: Not authorized to read table [tmp/] in schema [dfs.default]


[Error Id: 2e248da5-ba30-43f7-a983-1784d77cf81b ] (state=,code=0)
apache drill (dfs)>
```

(note there's now a permissions error I need to fix, but can at least now attempt to query the location).